# How to get number of students in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I get the count of different categories of students using MySQL
I have 6 categories in st_category field and 1 under st_handi field in table - 
Under st_category =>GEN, SC, ST, OBC, SGC, EWS and under es_handi=>PH

I need to the number of students from each categories gender wise. Example

```
       Male  | Female
      -------|-------
 GEN  | 54   |  239
 SC   | 19   |  9
 ST   | 5    |  19
 SGC  | 0    |  13
 OBC  | 19   |  9
 EWS  | 0    |  1
 PH   | 2    |  0
```

I tried may attempt to achieve the desired output but every attempt ends up with disappointment.

Is this possible?

Schema of Student Table

```
 ST_No | ST_Gender | ST_Category | ST_PH
 ------|-----------|-------------|-------
   1   | Male      | GEN         | Yes
   2   | Male      | GEN         | No
   3   | Female    | SC          | No
   4   | Male      | GEN         | No
   5   | Male      | ST          | No
   6   | Female    | GEN         | No
   7   | Male      | SC          | No
```

Above is sample data and schema of table.

Comment: Have you tried to construct a `select` statement?

Comment: Please show your exact table schema and some sample data for it

Comment: Please show the table structures.

Comment: @EdHeal I tried various options with select statement for below example is my last try I gave and finally I post my problem here -      `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM es_preadmission WHERE st_category='GEN' OR st_category='SC' OR st_category='ST' st_category='OBC' OR st_category='EWS' OR st_category='SGC' OR st_handi='PH' AND st_gender='male';`

Comment: @helloworld Kindly see the edited post I add sample data and schema of table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your table structure I do not know for sure, but from your description it sounds like your categories are in two fields. I am going to assume these fields are in the same table? You only need the WHERE clause if you want to limit results to just these categories.

```
SELECT st_category AS cat, st_gender, COUNT(studentPK)
FROM es_preadmission
WHERE st_category IN ('GEN','SC','ST',....,'SGC')
GROUP BY st_category, st_gender
UNION ALL
SELECT st_handi AS cat, st_gender, COUNT(studentPK)
FROM es_preadmission
WHERE st_handi = 'PH'
GROUP BY st_handi, st_gender
```

Comment: I really appreciate your assumption and accept your code, it really works but I am now confused where to add condition for class. Means what if I need this output class wise, say for class 4 and column name of class is st_class in same table

Comment: You could either add it to both of the WHERE clauses OR add st_class to the SELECT clause and wrap the entire query in another select statement: SELECT * FROM ( {SQL from above above with st_class added to each SELECT} ) WHERE st_class = 4

Answer (score 1):

Start with something like this:

```
SELECT Sum(Male) AS SumOfMale
FROM Students
GROUP BY Type;
```

Answer (score 0):

The first part of query counts male and female grouped by ST_Category, the second part add total of PH because, PH isn't a category but only a flag. (in the first query I've added the condition Table.PH = 'No', instead in the second query Table.PH = 'Yes'

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    ST_category,
    SUM(
    CASE
        WHEN ST_Gender = 'Male'
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    ) as Male,
    SUM(
    CASE
        WHEN ST_Gender = 'Female'
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    ) as Female
FROM Table
WHERE Table.PH = 'No'
GROUP BY ST_category

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    'PH',
    SUM(
    CASE
        WHEN ST_Gender = 'Male'
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    ) as Male,
    SUM(
    CASE
        WHEN ST_Gender = 'Female'
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    ) as Female
FROM Table
WHERE Table.PH = 'Yes'
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps...
for example some table like this one

```
CREATE TABLE students(
id SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(32),
gender VARCHAR(32),
category VARCHAR(32),
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

I'll do something like this

```
SELECT gender, category, COUNT(gender), COUNT(category) 
FROM students GROUP BY category, gender
```

[sqlfiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3b84/2/0)